# Edit Sagepay inframe CSS

Tags: css, iframe, opayo

I'm currently using the Sagepay inframe on a few sites.

The problem is that the inframe is not responsive and I would like to make it as responsive as possible considering it's in a iframe.

Is there a way to change the template or edit the template with my own CSS or html at all? I had heard it was a while ago but can't find anything about it now.

Comment: If you are using Protocol 3.00 (hopefully as older versions are being deprecated), you could try enabling the Responsive templates in My Sage Pay. Might not be what you need, but worth a look.

Rik

Comment: Hi Rik, thanks for this, I have set it to 3.00 but when i log into the my sagepay test section I don't see any ability to change the template? Where is this done?

Comment: Log into My Sage Pay, then click the Settings Tab (at the top r/hand side, assuming the user account has privileges to adjust account settings). Then click 'Settings' on the l/hand panel (confusingly!). In the bottom l/hand corner, you have the 'Account Settings' pane. If you click Edit here, you can then change the page template. Annoyingly, the 'Edit' button might require you to scroll the page down, but it is there.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking to Sagepay I found I could download the custom templates here: http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/server-inframe-integration-documents which you can then send to Sagepay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to make it responsive:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="google-maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d7098.94326104394!2d78.0430654485247!3d27.172909818538997!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385710909804" width="500" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 90%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/d5jtngy9/1/)